# How do I open a local SQLITE Database with php?

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I have got a local SQLITE database in the same folder as my index.html and my .php file.

Now I want to load the content of this SQLITE file with php in order to display it on my html page defined in the index.html file.

Can somebody give me advice on where to start-I am a complete beginner in designing databases.

Thanks.

Comment: Start by reading the PHP documentation about using SQLite databases. Then when you have a specific problem feel free to ask a question here.

Answer (score -1):

Please start from this useful link when you find a lot of elemental information about SQLITE Database connection.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice-helped me a lot.

Comment: @F.Klui If that help you please make the question as solved :)